# Flutter : Make Selected Card

Tags: flutter, dart

I have simple horizontal ListviewBuilder, inside it i have card which can be selected . But the problem is , when i selected one of card , all card is selected. 
I want is i only can selected 1 card, if i pick another card , deleted old selected and create new selected to the new card.
How to do this ?

> Something like this :

[image]

> My Failed Result

[image]

## It's my source code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IconMenu {
  final IconData iconName;
  final String titleIcon;
  IconMenu({this.iconName, this.titleIcon});
}

List<IconMenu> iconList = [
  IconMenu(iconName: Icons.ac_unit, titleIcon: "AC Unit"),
  IconMenu(iconName: Icons.access_alarm, titleIcon: "Alarm"),
  IconMenu(iconName: Icons.accessibility_new, titleIcon: "accessiblity"),
  IconMenu(iconName: Icons.add, titleIcon: "Add"),
];

class TestingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = "/testing-page";

  @override
  _TestingScreenState createState() => _TestingScreenState();
}

class _TestingScreenState extends State<TestingScreen> {
  bool selectedList = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 200,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: iconList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: () => setState(() => selectedList = !selectedList),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 150,
                    child: Card(
                      shape: selectedList
                          ? RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))
                          : null,
                      elevation: 5,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(iconList[index].iconName),
                          Text(iconList[index].titleIcon)
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your `bool selectedList = false;` should be `int selectedList = -1;` and you should compare that value with `index` passed to `itemBuilder` - if they are the same the card is selected, if not the card is not selected

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should take a `int` for the selected index.

`int selectedIndex=-1`

Then You can check for every card if its `position` is equal to the `selectedIndex` then its selected.

```
class _TestingScreenState extends State<TestingScreen> {
  int selectedIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 200,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: iconList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                    return InkWell(
                      onTap: () => setState(() => selectedIndex=position),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 150,
                        child: Card(
                          shape: (selectedIndex==position)
                              ? RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green))
                              : null,
                          elevation: 5,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(iconList[position].iconName),
                              Text(iconList[position].titleIcon)
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
  }   
}
```

Comment: This solution rebuilds the full list every time one car is selected/unselected, right?

Comment: No.It's the magic of flutter it doesn't rebuild.But for our human logic we can say yes it is

Comment: Ok, wrong sentence. I mean: rebuild all elements visible. I have one list that loads images from internet and looks like it is requesting the image when something changes in other elements of the list.

Comment: use cache_netwoek_image